# Table like control for C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, controls

I am looking for a free table like control to use in a C# form.

I am trying to avoid using the standard grid controls as I feel they are not versatile enough.

I would like the table cells to be big enough to contain input longer than one row.

I need to give my users the ability to write text in the table cells and I will finally go over the table and output its data as a report.

Comment: Tried `TableLayoutPanel`?  I've built very complicated layouts with it.  It works great, if you know how to use it properly.

Comment: Suggest you work out which exact feature the built-in table/grid controls don't give you first... Then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, shopping questions are off topic at SO.

Comment: In general i'm not looking to buy a control. If someone has an idea on how to make a control i would appreciate it too.

Answer (score 4):

DataGridView has the functionality you are looking for.  You can enable MultiLine in the individual columns by modifying the columns collection.  Click the "..." next to Collection in the columns field.  Then, in the "Edit Columns" screen, go to the "DefaultCellStyle" and click the "..." corresponding to that field.  In here, change "WrapMode" to true.  This is actually a very versatile and flexible control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am returning to GUI programming after 10+ years. Wouldn't have thought of a data grid. Using VS 2012 and C#.